# Binding a key to 'open -a Terminal .' on macOS

Tags: key-bindings, osx

I'd like to do something like this

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c t") (kbd "M-! /usr/bin/open -a Terminal . RET"))
```

... in order to open a (real, *the*) terminal from the current working directory in macOS with GNU Emacs 26.1. Although `/usr/bin/open -a Terminal .` opens a new terminal from within macOS, the above key binding doesn't work (nothing happens). Why? The buffer *Messages* shows `/bin/bash: /usr/bin/open-aTerminal.: No such file or directory`, so spaces seem to be ignored.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing some `SPC`s there. You can save a macro with `F3/F4` and then dump it with `M-x kmacro-edit-macro` (`C-c C-k RET`) to inspect the output. For example:

```
M-!         ;; shell-command
xfce4-terminal      ;; self-insert-command * 14
SPC         ;; self-insert-command
-e          ;; self-insert-command * 2
SPC         ;; self-insert-command
bash            ;; self-insert-command * 4
RET         ;; newline
```

Nevertheless, there is no need to use that "macro like" binding. It's better to just call `shell-command`. Even if Terminal didn't support passing a working directory you can exploit the fact that `shell-command` is running a full-fledged shell for you and simply `cd` before launching the terminal emulator:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c t")
                (lambda () (interactive)
                           (shell-command "cd .; xfce4-terminal")))
```

Btw, there is no point in starting the terminal in the current working directory. It's where any new process will be by default.

Comment: ... awesome, thanks a lot!